# The places from my Google Maps do not show up in Google Maps Search

Tags: google-maps

We have public Google Maps with lots of objects but when I do "Google Maps Search" these objects do not show up in the search results (even when I select 'user created maps only'). 
What should I do to make them appear?

Link to the map: http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=107873947602648971741.000465c62e537697c2371&z=7

Answer (score 2):

It appears that Google removed some of the functionality for searching user created maps.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=4f150fb453c99abd&hl=en

Comment: So there is no way to make my maps searchable except to duplicate the in google places?

Comment: Looks that way - more info/research here - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/maps/thread?tid=66ef35d2ecd14932&hl=en - hope this helps.